# Passing a json response parameter in another request on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSDictionary json response object which is printed after calling a service URL.

```
Looks like this:

{
geofenceType="a";
resourceType="b";
requestType="c";
monitoringType="d";
},
{
geofenceType="a1";
resourcetype="b1";
requestType="c1";
monitoringType="d1";
}, ...and so on for different users.
```

Now I have a button infront of each user in a tableViewController, and on pressing the button, I need to call another service URL which takes as parameters the geofenceType and the requestType of that user. Can you help me with how to pass the parameters.

Comment: Is your question regarding getting the parameters out of this NSDictionary or how to pass the parameters in a new request (presumably NSURLRequest)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly give each cellButton (When created in cellForRowATIndexPath)should be assigned a tag..supposedly indexPath.row.From your response it seems u have array of dictionaries.Set the Array in  datasource method.

Then in the button selector..

use this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [yourArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
```

finally

```
NSLog(@"[dict valueForKey:@"geofenceType"]");
```

shall give u the desired value

Comment: I have a json array in cellForRow method which I have to pass on to the buttonPressed method where I retrieve those parameters. How do I pass that json array to that method?

Comment: Declare that array in .h file so that u can access the same array in different functions

Comment: In cellforRow method: JSONDecoder *decoder=[[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions: JKParseOptionNone];
NSArray *json =[objectWithdata:data]; (json array now has the above details of all users) 
array1=json; (array1 is defined in  .h file) 
now the control goes the buttonPressed:withevent: method :Here I have a local array defined as: local=[array1 objectAtIndex:sender.tag  ;

It is throwing an exception.

Comment: do I need to make array1 as static?

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in several ways, one of the simplest is to assign a button.tag property in cellForRow method:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
//other code
}
```

Then, in button handler you can obtain your item like this:

```
-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton)sender;
    yourItemForRow = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag];

    //use yourItemForRow
}
```

Comment: I have already written this...the thing that I am not able to figure out is that how to pass that json object(which is in a different function) to the cellforRow method so that I could get the details of a particular user and from there I can easily pass those parameters in the buttonPressed method.

Comment: You are doing wrong things..there is one way to do what you want but that will be not right...